# Using gsub on a form text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've integrated a wysiwyg editor and I need to do some replacing in order to maintain inline compatibility. I've placed `params[:body].gsub()` at the start of the create method, before the params are saved into the database. However, I'm getting `undefined method`gsub' for nil:NilClass`

What's the best way to go about doing this?

```
  def emailblastcreate
    params[:body].gsub('class="wysiwyg-color-grey"' => 'style="color: #A9A9A9;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-blue"' => 'style="color: #333399;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-purple"' => 'style="color: #663399;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-red"' => 'style="color: #CC3333;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-orange"' => 'style="color: #FF6633;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-yellow"' => 'style="color: #FFCC33;"',
                                             'class="wysiwyg-color-green"' => 'style="color: #009933;"')
    email = Blast.create(blast_params)
    user = current_user
    PanelMailer.blast(user, email).deliver
  end
```

Comment: Need more info to help you, but that ...`for nil:NilClass` means that your `params[:body]` is blank. The `gsub` should go in the model and not the controller, too, but one thing at a time.

Comment: @CD-RUM Weirdly enough it isn't blank, can't get my head around it if I'm honest

Comment: Got your log output there with the `params`?

Comment: @CD-RUM  "body"=>"<span>TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest</span>"}

Comment: So then whatever object you're trying to save isn't saving, and your app is calling `gsub` on nothing. Post more of the log in your question. It might say `ROLLBACK` or similar somewhere.

Comment: @CD-RUM Added my controller code to the main thread, should I be calling gsub before I actually save it to the database? Or should I be saving first, then calling gsub and updating the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, editing params that way seems very strange to me (also your `gsub` should be `gsub!`—the bang makes it destructive, the former will need a new variable to be useful). If it was me, in your `Blast` model, I'd give this work to callbacks. [Note: pseudocode and not tested but the idea is there.]

```
class Blast

  before_save :gsub_colours if wysiwig_colours?

  private

  def gsub_colours
    hex_colours.each do |key, value|
      return unless body.include?(key)
      body.gsub!(key, value)
    end
  end

  def wysiwyg_colours?
    body.include?('wysiwyg-color-')
  end

  def hex_colours
    { 'class="wysiwyg-color-grey"' => 'style="color: #A9A9A9;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-blue"' => 'style="color: #333399;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-purple"' => 'style="color: #663399;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-red"' => 'style="color: #CC3333;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-orange"' => 'style="color: #FF6633;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-yellow"' => 'style="color: #FFCC33;"',
      'class="wysiwyg-color-green"' => 'style="color: #009933;"'
    }
  end
end
```

Hope that takes you in the right direction.